# How to make a query with AND condition in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

How can I make a query with **AND** condition in Mongoid?

Comment: what conditions? Equal to 'x' and greater than 'y' ... ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can chain `where` statements or include multiple conditions to the `where` call.

```
Model.where(condition_a: :a, condition_b: :b).all
```

or

```
Model.where(condition_a: :a).where(condition_b: :b).all
```

Comment: Depending on your conditions, the second `where` may silently overwrite keys from the first `where`, i.e. `where(foo: 'a').where(foo: 'b')` is not equivalent to `where(foo: 'a').and(foo: 'b')`

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can chain things using `.and(other_thing:'value')`

For instance, `Model.where(awesome:true).and(other_thing:true)`